# Meteor : display with handlebars client side nested object

Tags: javascript, object, meteor, nested, handlebars.js

I have JSON from helper :

```
 {
  "perms": [
     {
         "userId": "rA5s5jSz7q9ZSCcNJ",
         "perms": [
             {
                 "moduleName": "Gallery",
                 "container": {
                     "ImageUpload": {
                         "addImage": false,
                         "modifyImage": false,
                         "removeImage": false
                     },
                     "Article": {
                         "readArticle": false,
                         "createArticle": false,
                         "modifyArticle": false,
                         "removeArticle": false,
                         "archiveArticle": false
                     }
                 }
             }
         ]
     },
     {
         "userId": "RrmynmmngJEMsRRpk",
         "perms": [
             {
                 "moduleName": "Gallery",
                 "container": {
                     "ImageUpload": {
                         "addImage": false,
                         "modifyImage": false,
                         "removeImage": false
                     },
                     "Article": {
                         "readArticle": false,
                         "createArticle": false,
                         "modifyArticle": false,
                         "removeArticle": false,
                         "archiveArticle": false
                     }
                 }
             }
         ]
     }
 ]
```

My JS is :

```
    'userWithRights':function() {
        Meteor.call('genereObjectPermission',function(err, resp){
           Session.set('responseServer', resp);
           });
        responseServer = Session.get('responseServer')
        return _.map(responseServer, function(value, key) { return {key: key, value: value}; })

    },'iterateInValue':function(){
        return _.map(this, function(value, key) { return {key: key, value: value}; })

}
```

And my HTML code (result of much trial) :

```
{{#each userWithRights}}
  <p> {{key}} </p>
  {{#each value}}
    <li>{{this.userId}}</li>
    {{#each perms}}
      <li><li>{{moduleName}}</li></li>
      {{#each test58}}
          <li><li><li>{{key}}</li></li></li
      {{/each }}
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

So, I'm a little lost in handlebars, when I must iterate in  `Object  { key : value }` I succeed with difficulty, but when I must iterate in an Object nested in other Object I can't :

```
{"container": { "ImageUpload": { "removeImage": false }}}
```

I try to get a result like this:

- rA5s5jSz7q9ZSCcNJ
- Gallery
- ImageUpload

  - addImage : true
  - modifyImage : false
  - removeImage : false
- Article

  - readArticle : true
  - createArticle : false
  - modifyArticle :false

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a #with helper and access keys using @key:

```
{{#each userWithRights}}
  <p> {{key}} </p>
  <ul>
  {{#each value}}
    <li>{{this.userId}}</li>
    {{#each perms}}
      <li>{{moduleName}}</li>
      {{#with container}}
        {{#with ImageUpload}}
          <li>{{@key}}</li>
        {{/with}}
        <ul>
        {{#each ImageUpload}}
          <li>{{@key}}: {{this}}</li>
        {{/each}}
        </ul>
        {{#with Article}}
          <li>{{@key}}</li>
        {{/with}}
        <ul>
        {{#each Article}}
          <li>{{@key}}: {{this}}</li>
        {{/each}}
        </ul>
      {{/with}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
{{/each}}
```

Hope that helps!